# Alignment issue with the accept reminder message in Activity -> Questions tab

Tags: bug, design, activity

There is an alignment issue in the **Activity -> Questions** tab's accept reminder message. It is not aligned correctly.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Alignment issue]

The message in plain text:

> Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?