# Is the accept/bounty reminder still shown after the Activity page revamp in 2021?

Tags: support, user-interface, accepted-answer, question-lists, activity

Back in 2019-2020, there was still an accept/bounty reminder that was shown on the user's profile page (despite the possible layout bug): [Alignment issue with the accept reminder message in Activity -> Questions tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329878/241919)

> Screenshot for reference:
>
> > [image: Alignment issue]
>
> The message in plain text:
>
> > Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?

This reminder would be shown if the criteria mentioned in [When is the message "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?" displayed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214877/when-is-the-message-have-you-considered-accepting-an-answer-or-starting-a-bount/348533#348533) were fulfilled.

Then, the Activity page was revamped in 2021: [New responsive Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/372049/new-responsive-activity-page).

After the revamp, is this reminder still shown anywhere?

---

*P.S. This question is just asking for clarification of an existing feature. Please do not discuss the merit of this feature in this post. Depending on the answer received, the OP may post a follow-up question. Otherwise, feel free to post a new question on your own.*

Comment: What stops you from starting a bounty on your own question for science's sake?

Comment: @Luuklag the reminder should only be shown on a recent question asked within 60 days that also has answers, and on a site where I have downvote privilege but not close vote privilege, which is to say: I don't have any eligible questions unless I ask a new question on another SE site.

Comment: I just posted a question on Mathematics. Currently, all the criteria have been fulfilled except "The question is at least three days old and not more than 60 days old". So I guess I'll wait for three days and find out :) Although, by then, you should already have an answer...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I recently posted a [question on Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4454279/a-combined-arithmetic-and-geometric-sequence-question), which now fulfills all the criteria mentioned in [When is the message [...] displayed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214877/when-is-the-message-have-you-considered-accepting-an-answer-or-starting-a-bount/348533#348533):

- You are viewing your own questions ✅
- You have the privilege to vote down ✅
- You do not have the privilege to cast close votes ✅
- The question does not have an accepted answer ✅
- The question is at least three days old and not more than 60 days old ✅
- The question has at least one answer and is not closed ✅
- The question does not have a currently active bounty and has not previously had a bounty ✅

> Is the accept/bounty reminder still shown after the Activity page revamp in 2021?

Yes, it is still shown:

[image: Image showing accept/bounty reminder in the Questions tab: "Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?"]