# Button to view "Questions with no accepted answer"

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, accepted-answer

It would be nice if, across all SE sites, there was a button on the "Questions" page for each user, that allowed you to filter your own questions which you haven't accepted an answer for yet. I probably have many questions buried down my question list that haven't been accepted because I've forgotten about them. A filter on the question page would help these bubble up to the top and might encourage more people to accept answers.

Something like "No accepted answer" perhaps?

[image]

Comment: FWIW, it's already possible to do this [via the site search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aq+hasaccepted%3Ano).

Comment: I'm aware. Doing so requires you to remember a search query and think to type it in however. If it's a button that's there already, there's a much higher likelihood of users discovering it, clicking it, and realising that they really should've accepted that answer to the question they asked in 2011 that perfectly solved their problem.

Comment: IMHO, this is an XY problem down to the system being wrong. Accepted answers are misleading. Finding posts *without* accepted answers is thus incorrect behaviour that the system drives by having meaningless acceptances.

Comment: I think that's a lot of generalisations stated as facts. Some accepted answers can be misleading, but isn't the point of having accepted answers to prioritise the answer that OP found most useful? Upvotes will prioritise the answer that the community found most useful anyway. I also think incentivising and making it easier for OP to accept answers may provide more incentive to answer questions for those who care about karma and badges etc.

Comment: "*isn't the point of having accepted answers to prioritise the answer that OP found most useful?*" yes. And this information is useless in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: I'm not seeing the XY problem here. If you find accepted answers to be useless then that's fine, but adding a button that allows me to filter questions without accepted answers more easily wouldn't adversely affect you in any way.

Comment: "*isn't the point of having accepted answers to prioritise the answer that OP found most useful?*" [not anymore on some sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/369914/241919).

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. Alright, that's interesting. I presume that, as a cultural rule, we still want to persuade OPs to accept answers though, no?

Comment: "*we still want to persuade OPs to accept answers though, no?*" I've yet to see a reason to. Other than giving the answerer reputation. We've [stopped displaying the acceptance rate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136951/lets-stop-displaying-a-users-accept-rate) *because* it lead to worse experience for askers. So, if you intend to badger people into accepting - please don't. We don't want that. That's on top of the already dubious value of acceptance itself. But you seem uninterested in how it detracts from the site, so I won't delve into it further.

Comment: @Lou on one hand, [yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378856/241919). On the other hand, [no](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78438/241919) (and thus a few updates that reduced the importance of acceptance)

Comment: If it's not in the site culture any more then those are reasonable points. Anyway, my interest was in "badgering" myself to accept, not anyone else. But thanks for explaining the context behind it - I wasn't aware that the site view had changed since I started using SO.